# Interpretation of "～のようなものがある" and "どうにかなってしまった"

Tags: grammar

> 以前にはなかった、私へのちょっとした好奇心のようなものがあるような気がして、私は胸を高鳴らせた。
>
> *Unlike before, having a feeling that there is a slight curiosity towards me, my heart throbs*

*Speaking is currently being teased by a girl.*

Feels excessively wordy to me, what the difference between 好奇心のような気がして vs  好奇心のようなものがあるような気がして ?

> ＧＰＳ機能が、どうにかなってしまったとでもいうのだろうか
>
> The gps functions (of the phone) , let's say it somehow became like this. ??

Speaker is lost in a forest, and his gps on his phone isn't working.

Really not sure about this one.

Thank you

Comment: @will  Grouped these two as long unintelligible kana strings, edited the first question to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 好奇心の**ようなものがあるような気がして**
>
> どうにかなってしまった**とでもいうのだろうか**
>
> Feels excessively wordy to me, what the difference between 好奇心のような気がして vs

Two totally different expressions, but you felt something is common between the two. That is probably 'excessively wordy.'

These are subjective expressions. They are not likely to appear in formal objective writings.

> the difference between 好奇心のような気がして vs
>
> > 以前にはなかった、私へのちょっとした好奇心のようなものがあるような気がして、私は胸を高鳴らせた。

The core of the statement is 好奇心がある気がする, but our grammar allows us to *express our feelings more accurately*, just as we feel it.

The speaker is not sure yet if it's really 好奇心, but so far it's just ちょっとした好奇心のようなもの.

The speaker is also not sure if it's really there, so the expression becomes あるような気がする.

There might be really not much there yet, and the speaker is either or both expecting too much from nothing or being overly cautious.

The other one should be actually enough if it's どうにかなってしまったのだろうか, but expressing it as とでもいうのだろうか is a style issue. One might enjoy reading it, the other might stop reading it.

---

[Replying to additional question]

> i'm actually more curious about the "どうにかなってしまった

If it's どうにかなった, it becomes less clear; it can also mean a good news.
If it's どうにかなったとでもいうのだろうか, it could also mean that the problem at issue might have been resolved on the contrary to the speaker's expectation.

If you want to know the structure of it in detail, then I think it needs a separate thread.

Comment: Ok, i see for the first one, for the 2nd one i'm actually more curious about the "どうにかなってしまった rather than "とでもいうのだろうか" . The latter, i assume follows a concept related to https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21156/function-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-in-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B.  Thank you for your help !

Comment: I've just added the answer in the answer section above.

Comment: Don't need a full breakdown, but its just seems like a very vague and pointless statement. " ＧＰＳ機能が, ... (let say..) Somehow or another it  became like this (regrettably). " .  It was already stated that the gps was not working,  so what exactly is this trying to say?

Comment: It's natural to say something like あら？動かなくなった。何かがどうにかなってしまったのかな？

Comment: hm, in other words, it just a long winded way of say "hm, what's wrong with it"?

Comment: I don't know your previous sentence, but we typically say "Oh, no, it stopped functioning. What's wrong with it?"