# Potential verb + でも: meaning?

Tags: translation, meaning, potential-form, particle-でも

The sentence is:

> あの    狐ねばばあに  餌付けでも   　されたか？

餌付け - is a potential form of the verb.

What role is でも playing here?

Comment: You might consider [looking 餌付け up in a dictionary](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A4%8C%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91-445261).  By the way, it's always appreciated if askers can include some context in their questions.

Answer (score 3):

でも is a particle which has several meanings. In this case it roughly means "～ or something like that", "... for example" or "maybe". See: [Function of "でも" in "とでも言うべきであろうか"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21156/5010) and [confusing usage of でも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34029/5010)

餌付け【えづけ】 is a [**noun** derived from the masu stem of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010). It means "taming an animal by means of feeding it", and it can work as a suru-verb. There is no potential meaning in 餌付け on its own. It's usually not used with a human being, but apparently it's used figuratively here.